# How to compile a JS file in CRA public folder?

Tags: reactjs, babeljs, create-react-app

I want to compile a Javascript file in my public folder so that I can use ES6 syntax to develop it, but it compiles to a <ES6 friendly version so that it can be included in other files with cross-browser compatibility. It would be great if I could do this without ejecting and if I could use CRA's existing babel configuration. If I can get this working, I will include this command in my production build script to compile and replace this file before it's all packaged up.

I've tried installing `babel-cli` and it seems to run on the given file, but it does not produce a file with <ES6 compatible syntax.

This is the command I'm running:

```
npx babel public/file.js -o public/compiled-file.js
```

No other configuration has been applied beyond what is provided with CRA.

I would expect the file to change any ES6 syntax to <ES6 compatible syntax such as `const` and `let` to `var`, but it's not doing any of that.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this to work by adding `@babel/cli` and `@babel/preset-env` to my project's `package.json` dev dependencies.

After that, I was able to do the following command to compile this file as needed:

```
npx babel public/file.js --out-file public/compiled-file.js --presets=@babel/preset-env
```